Issues using @Lob annotation in JPA to save book description
I am developing a Java application using JPA for data persistence. In my application, I need to save a book description that often exceeds the default varchar(255) limit. To address this, I used the @Lob annotation on the book description field. However, when saving the entity to the database, I noticed that the description is stored as an integer representing the number of characters in the description, instead of storing the full text. I would like to understand what is causing this behavior and how I can fix it so that the description is correctly saved as text.
image 1
image 2
I expect the description field in the database to store the full text of the book's description, even if it exceeds 255 characters, instead of storing only a numerical value representing the length of the text.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to remove both the @Lob annotation and the columnDefinition, and instead provide a length. The JPA implementation is supposed to determine the suitable type on its own. For example when you say you want to store strings with 65000 chars length and your database does not support varchar of that size, it will automatically choose another type of your database that can hold such long strings.
You would only use @Lob, if you really want to store your data specifically as large objects in your database (if supported).
